# custom lookup with checkbox values in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lookup, checkbox

I want to create a inputtext field with a lookup icon next to it and when i click the lookup image, it has to display all the values with checkbox and when i select a checkbox or more, the text field has to be filled with the checkbox values with comma seperated.

can someone guide me with the code

Answer (score 0):

Although no one is going to write code for you, I'd advise taking a look at [Roll Your Own "Lookup" Popup Window](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/) by Jeff Douglas who goes through and explains how to do this.

If you want to select a list of records (a bit like a List View), you'd need to use a Wrapper Class. You can find an article which discusses exactly how to do this [here with selecting and processing](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) records as you describe.

Otherwise, you might want to check out how you can do this using JavaScript. There's a [nice tutorial here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/checkbox/group.php) which should point you in the right direction.